# bash: export variable security, echo $var | prog, clear $var?

Tags: bash, security, passwords

i am looking for a way to secure some programs that i have been working on.
some set or change a users password, looking to create a GUI for login now and realized how insecure i have been writing the software.

i am using gtkdialog as my frontend. this uses GTK+

the password entered in gui is hidden from the screen, and the password is exported to a variable.

the variable could possibly not be exported as part of a solution ( i can work around this though it would be better if i did not have to )

please provide a way to securely handle the password either within gtkdialog and/or securely handle the password within a bash script.

example of "unlock" usage:

```
export password="pass"
echo "$password" | sudo
```

example of password changing:

```
password="old pass"
new_pass="new pass"
echo "$password\n$new_pass\n$new_pass" | passwd
```

thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Do you actually need to handle passwords in the first place? `sudo` can be configured to allow particular users or groups to run particular commands without password. Whether this is feasible or not in your scenario depends on what command is supposed to be run, of course.

Comment: it is not feasible in my case, this is an attempt to cut possible dependency issues as well. also writing a program for a user to change their own password is due to a lack of alternate options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily as secure as you want, but two options:

Unset the var when done

> unset $password

Or if $password is only used inside of on function, you could use a local var

> local $password="pass"

Additionally, you don't want to be using `export` to set your secure vars... that will make them a shell var...

> password="pass"

Comment: this is as far as i have been able to come up with myself. thats why i came here to ask for something better. i am quite sure that whatever i do it will be insecure using gtkdialog to set the variable.